# How can I copy from one mysql table to another table with different column type definitions?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy from one mysql table to another table with different column type definition... from varchar to int

I am trying to copy the column codigo which is a varchar, to codProducto in another table which is an int.

This is what I tried so far:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (codProducto)
SELECT CAST(codigo as SIGNED)
FROM desarrolloproductos;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''

INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (codProducto)
SELECT CONVERT(codigo, UNSIGNED)
FROM desarrolloproductos;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What values do you have in the `varchar` column? Is it nullable?

Comment: its a varchar(20) not null

Comment: sorry, the values are all varchars... but they are ids from codebars. 
they are only represented as varchars but they all are numbers....

Comment: Can you have leading spaces or empty strings?

Comment: yes, indeed it was that problem, wrong characters.
Also after that, I realized that the string representation was bigger than a normal int, so I had to change the type to bigint.

problem solved, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some lost wrong characters at the varchars column.
Also after that, I realised that the string representation was bigger than a normal int, so I had to change the type to bigint . problem solved, thank you –